# How to install polyfill aurelia

Tags: aurelia, polyfills

I am using aurelia-validation plugin and i want to use their BootstrapFormRenderer when there is an error: https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#custom-renderers

I really need to make it work on IE 11 and as they say i need to polyfill for making it working.

How can i install the polyfill and use it in aurelia to make it work with IE 11 ?
Here is the link for the polyfill: https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I can answer your question based on using the Aurelia CLI with RequireJS as your module loader/bundler.

The first thing you'll need to do is use NPM to install the polyfill.

```
 npm install --save element-closest
```

After you have done this, you'll need to update your `aurelia.json` file. This is located in the `aurelia_project` folder. If you are still working with the same setup as given to you when your ran `au new`, then there will be two bundles, `app-bundle.js` and `vendor-bundle.js`, configured. The `vendor-bundle` configuration has a `prepend` property that already has some things configured in it. The prepend section is where you want to put your polyfill, as the module bundler will simply copy/paste the contents of the file with the polyfill in to the beginning of bundle file. It won't wrap it in a module or anything, and thus at run time, the polyfill code will automatically execute, adding the polyfill if it needs to. I would recommend adding the polyfill as the first item in your `vendor-bundle` prepend section. At the very least, it needs to be placed before `require.js` in the prepend section. You can see an example below:

```
    "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
    "prepend": [
      "node_modules/element-closest/element-closest.js",
      "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
      {
        "path": "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird-no-long-stacktraces.js",
        "env": "stage & prod"
      },
      {
        "path": "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird.js",
        "env": "dev"
      },
      "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
    ],
```

After doing this, and running either `au build` or `au run`, this is what the beginning of my `scripts/vendor-bundle.js` file looks like:

### [image]

**Orignal Answer Below**:

It's been a week since you asked the question and there hasn't been an answer. The reason is your question is extremely vague.

The answer would depend on what module loader/bundler you are using when you build your app. Are you using the Aurelia CLI? If so, are you using RequireJS or Webpack?

Note that this isn't really an Aurelia question so much as a question regarding whatever bundler you're using. Also, note that, as a last resort, polyfills can simply be loaded using script tags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am using Aurelia CLI with RequireJS. I will try to install it with the script tag but I really want to install it properly, and like you said if it this the last resort i will do like that then.

Comment: With that information, I can provide an answer that will work for you.